# Feedback loop frequency

Tags: feedback, frequency

Is their an average frequency range of a feedback loop.

One created by a speaker and a mic to be slightly more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean in livesound situations? If so, it depends on soo many factors that it is impossible to give a average frequency range. But something i noticed when working with a band that only use in-ears is that feedback through FoH started (if at all) around the lower midrange. I think this is common due to the way lower frequencies radiate. With the band i toured with, a common frequencyarea that feedbacked was around 160-200, probably due to the many acoustic guitars used that resonate around these frequencies.

Remember that what i say only applies to the situation i am in with this band and certain circumstances. If you use wedges and those types of monitors other areas might feedback more often due  to the length between the wedges and the mics etc etc. Like i said in the beginning, it depends on so many factors... Still, hope this helps :).

Comment: Btw, if you want to learn the sound of different types of feedback loops, i would recommend to practice with this tool: http://www.mediacollege.com/media-guru/audio/frequency-trainer.html I find it very well built.

Comment: I'll post a picture of my setup to give more information tomorrow. 
But you gave me more info to refine my question. Ty for the link will check it out

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the frequency as it happens, try this nice little freebie - [Sonoma Feedback Detector](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/feedback-detector/id560799394?mt=8)

[image]

No affiliation, I've just found it useful myself.

Very rough guesses…

- below 200 Hz could be through the floor
- between 800Hz & 2k can be the back of a mic, to the wedges, or when cupped.
- 3k or over will be a mic directly facing its feedback source.

Comment: mine was average of 5400hz... nice app. 

So feedback loop isn't always in the same range.

Comment: Glad you liked it.. & no, feedback is very much dependent on what's pointing at what, how loud it is & what the building's made of. Rarely the same twice.